# Wordpress Multisite and Stripe Subscription?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming, stripe-payments

The project is to have a WordPress Multisite where visitors can signup (Stripe Subscriptions) and have they own site created on the spot if the payment is successful.

Then, a webhook listener will be added to receive failed renewals and so forth.

What I need to code is my custom payment/subscription plugin and a custom MySQL table called wp_subscriptions. What columns would you use:

- subscription_id (obviously)
- user_id (the signed up user, and admin of a site)
- site_id (the multisite site id)
- plan_id (the stripe plan)
- subscription_ key (the stripe subscription id)
- start_date (when it starts)
- renewal_date (next renewal)
- end_date (when it ends if cancellation requested)
- status (the status: active, payment_failed (grace period), cancellation_pendind, cancelled)

I feel like I am simply cloning the stripe's subscription object... What is the best way to go about this?

Lazhar

Answer (score 0):

Those all seem like reasonable values that will all serve a useful purpose within your application.  For what it's worth, there's a lot more in the Stripe Subscription object than what you've got there; it looks like you're just storing what you need to - both from the Stripe object and from your own domain - so it definitely looks good to me.